# AI proving theorems

Tags: artificial-intelligence, complexity-theory, theorem-proving

I am a mathematician and I was discussing with colleagues about the possibility of computers proving mathematical theorems (or as we put, AlphaMath), and it turns out we have no rigorous convincing arguments either way. So I would like to ask:

> Question: What are the available rigorous arguments about whether a classical computer (excluding quantum Turing machine for the moment, though that's also of interest) can be built to prove, for example, P is not equal to NP?

By a classical computer, I am assuming computers can be like a billion times faster than it is now, as long as electrons don't have strong objections. I choose P vs NP because I feel a convincing argument might involve some complexity theory itself, but feel free to replace if you like others, or if you don't believe P vs NP is provable, etc. Please feel free to close or move my question if it's not adequate here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: A little clarification: As theorem-proving itself is NP-complete if appropriately defined(right?), it probably doesn't count if for example such efficient Turing machines exist, but the problem of building it is also "NP-hard."

Comment: The theorem that no computer program exists that could prove arbitrary theorems given arbitrary finite resources was proved independently by Alonso Church and Alan Turing. Yet some new mathematical theorems had been proved by computers. [Robbins conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robbins_algebra) is probably the most cited example of a well-known conjecture that was first proved true by a computer, however recently there were other such examples.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I was definitely wrong and I guess by theorem-proving I was thinking of somethings like "given a statement and an integer n, determine if a proof of length <= n exists." (and poly. time means poly. in n)...